# How to navigate an octave plot?

Tags: graph, plot, octave

In Octave, when a plot is created, how do I move along the axes?
I have managed only to zoom in/out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- **Zoom in and out**
  Ctrl + Mousewheel
- **Move up and down**
  Mousewheel
- **Move left and right**
  Shift + Mousewheel

Comment: @Michael I am running linux sled11 and my octave version is 3.4.0 and it works exactly like posted above^^

Comment: I have octave 3.2.4. (That's what you get with apt-get). I'll try your version. I'm plotting with plot() btw